# AnimateKeyframes animate for the UILabel's value

Tags: swift

I ran the code below and the label was moved perfectly. But I want to increase the value of the label at the same time with each move. I have tried many ways but it doesn't work.

```
    UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 6, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: (0 / 6), relativeDuration: (2 / 6), animations: {
            self.label.transform = label.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 50) //OK
            //I want the value of the label to be increased from 0 to 5 (exactly equal to the duration of this key frame)
        })
        
        UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: (2 / 6), relativeDuration: (2 / 6), animations: {
            self.label.transform = label.transform.translatedBy(x: 50, y: 0) //OK
            //Then I want the value of the label to decrease from 5 to 0
        })
    }, completion: nil)
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to do it within the animation block, you can use `Timer` and change label's text property with it.

Example, in your case I would do it like this:

```
var tick = 0
let duration: TimeInterval = 6
let countTo = 5
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: duration / (2 * Double(countTo)), repeats: true) { timer in
    tick += 1
    let mod = tick % countTo
    if tick >= countTo, tick < countTo * 2 {
        label.text = String(countTo - mod)
    } else {
        label.text = String(mod)
    }
        
    if tick >= countTo * 2 {
        timer.invalidate()
    }
}
    
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [], animations: {
            
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        label.transform = label.transform.translatedBy(x: 0, y: 50)
    })
            
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.5, relativeDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        label.transform = label.transform.translatedBy(x: 50, y: 0)
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

This way you can set duration you need and to what number you want to count to and back to 0 within the duration.